# Preloaded css file containing nothing but comments still affects Largest Contentful Paint

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, lighthouse

I have been trying to understand how to optimise the LCP for my website.

At the start my LCP is 2-3 seconds with my css file included, and under 1 second without it.

Following https://web.dev/defer-non-critical-css/ I preload my css file, and inline my critical styles.

This is how I preload my styles:

```
  <link rel="preload" href="/static/style.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

This had no effect whatsoever on the LCP reported by lighthouse.
At this point, just to make sure there were no hidden "critical" styles in my css file, I replaced the content of `style.css` with 20k lines of comments.

**Preloading this 20k comments file caused my LCP to be 5 seconds!** "Time to interactive" was also five seconds.

What the hell is going on!? How can a preloaded css containing nothing but comments possibly affect the LCP time? Obviously it does not really change the rendering time of the actual content of the viewport.

**EDIT:**
This might actually be *caused* by the simultated throttling in Lighthouse

This Image shows simulated throttling OFF. You can see the LCP is well before the theme finishes loading.

[image]

And here the only difference is that I turned simulated throttling ON. You can see the page isn't rendered without styles at all, and the FCP and LCP are well after the css (purple) is downloaded.

[image]

Is it likely that Lighthouse is giving me funny results?

Comment: Can you turn this into a quick test page, I have a feeling you have missed a critical point but it is impossible to tell from your explanation (as from your explanation it appears you have done everything correctly).

Comment: p.s. removed the SEO tag for you as otherwise the "no SEO on StackOverflow" zealots will close your question without reading it. 

Comment: @GrahamRitchie if no-one has any ideas then I can host an example somewhere. But it should be fairly easy to replicate (just preload a css file full of comments and look in lighthouse)

Comment: What is so surprising about this? Your whole CSS still needs to be _parsed_, for the browser to _know_ that it is just 20k comments. Before it hasn’t done that, it doesn’t know that this is not going to affect layout in any way.

Comment: @CBroe it's surprising because everything in the viewport is rendered correctly without needing that css file. But the LCP occurs after downloading the css, even if the css is just comments. Are you saying that the LCP is necessarily always after the preload styles have finished being downloaded?

Comment: @CBroe https://web.dev/optimize-lcp/ in the section "Defer non-critical CSS"